# How to assign one value to the entire (or partial) list in Python?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I have `List = [0, 1, 2, 3]` and I want to assign all of them a number say, 5: `List = [5, 5, 5, 5]`. I know I can do `List = [5] * 4` easily. But I also want to be able to assign say, 6 to the last 3 elements.

```
List = [5, 5, 5, 5]

YourAnswer(List, 6, 1, 3)

>> [5, 6, 6, 6]
```

where `YourAnswer` is a function.

Anything similar would be helpful. Prefer to avoid for-loop. But if there is no known possibility, please tell me.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `1` in the function call?

Comment: 1 means the 2nd element, 3 means the last element

Comment: Then slice assignment is what you want, like `List[1:4] = [6] * 3` as seen in some answers below.

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you want to create a new list with the given values, or whether you want to modify the content of an existing list.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot community. Never really used slice assignment before.

Comment: @LieRyan Edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually use the slice assignment mechanism to assign to part of the list.

```
>>> some_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> some_list[:1] = [5]*1
>>> some_list[1:] = [6]*3
>>> some_list
[5, 6, 6, 6]
```

This is beneficial if you are updating the same list, but in case you want to create a new list, you can simply create a new list based on your criteria by concatenation

```
>>> [5]*1 + [6]*3
[5, 6, 6, 6]
```

You can wrap it over to a function

```
>>> def YourAnswer(lst, repl, index, size):
    lst[index:index + size] = [repl] * size


>>> some_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> YourAnswer(some_list, 6, 1, 3)
>>> some_list
[0, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: worth noting that `[x]*n` copies the same `x` `n` times. Therefore, modifying any list element will have the effect of modifying all of them

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: True but only for reference Type.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [138]: def func(lis,x,y,z):
   .....:     return lis[:y]+[x]*z
   .....: 

In [139]: lis=[5,5,5,5]

In [140]: func(lis,6,1,3)
Out[140]: [5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use + to implement it

```
def createList(val1, n1, val2, n2):
    return [val1] * n1 + [val2]*n2
```